# Cordova Network Information Plugin doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, cordova, vue.js

I have built a Mobile application with Cordova, Onsen UI and Vue.js. While working with the network connectivity, I have installed the cordova plugin

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information
```

then to check the type of the connection I have used the following instruction

```
var network = navigator.connection.type
alert(network);
```

But it shows undefined. After printing `navigator.connection` in the console log it shows the following properties

1. downlink
2. effectiveType
3. onchange
4. rtt

But When I use the following  instruction

```
navigator.connection.effectiveType
```

it shows the type.

Another problem is that when I don't have the internet connection the `effecticeType` property shows 3g/4g.

Why is that? Then how can I get the confirmation that there is no internet connection? Please Help me out.

Comment: When you say "no internet connection", are you referencing no wi-fi connection? Are you sure there is no cellular connection as well?

Comment: I am referencing to no wifi connection.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have properly installed the plugin, here's the function I use to check if WiFi or data connection is active:

```
function checkConnection() {
    console.log('checkConnection()');

    if(typeof (window.cordova) === 'undefined') {
        return true; // we are on the browser
    } else if(navigator.connection.type == Connection.NONE) {
        return false; // offline
    } else {
        return true; // online
    }
}
```

Comment: I have applied your code in my **main.js** file and then called in created() hook. But it still not working.